# Log of file changes on MacOS

Tags: macos, logging, file-io, macos-sierra, audit-trail

I'm currently looking for solutions for logging actions performed on files/directories anywhere on a MacOS system to create a log that could be used as an audit trail.

The solution would need to list:

- the user account performing the action
- the name and location of the file/directory that the action is being performed on
- information about the nature of the action (was it moved, created, copied, deleted, transferred/downloaded, permission changed etc)
- the timestamp of the action

Essentially we want to know who's touched what files at what time and what did they do with them on a MacOS system that's being access by multiple users.

How much of this information can I get out of the existing MacOS system logs? What tools are some of the better tools out there for logging this kind of information? Would it help to lock down the search area to a smaller number of *tracked* directories?